# chrome.scripting.executeScript in chrome-extension:// page in manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extension that I'm porting to manifest v3, which needs to inject an iframe into some available document.

In manifest v2, there was always a background page with an available document, but with manifest v3 service workers don't have a document.

When my extension is installed, it opens a `chrome-extension://<my_extension_id>/install.html` page, which has a document, so I figured that would be a valid page to inject my iframe into.

However, the install.html page is showing an error when I try to use `chrome.scripting.executeScript` from my service worker:

```
Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://<my_extension_id>/install.html".
Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

I have the following defined in my manifest.json file:

```
  "permissions": [
    ...
    "scripting",
    ...
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

The script execution code looks like this:

```js
  let [activeTab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
    args: [someUrl],
    func: (url) => { 
      const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.src = url;
      document.body.append(iframe);
    }
  });
```

Note that activeTab is the extension install.html page upon installation.

What can I change to allow this script to execute in my `chrome-extension://<my_extension_id>/install.html` page?

Comment: Content scripts don't work with chrome-extension://*. I think executeScript is the same.

Comment: Put the code from `func` into your install.html's onMessage listener. Then send a message to trigger it.

Comment: Write <script src="install.js"></script> in install.html.